# Retrieving images using its path from server to android app

Tags: android

I have made an android app in which I store image path and their details into sql database and retrieve those data using  web service in an android app. The images path are of online web sites at this time.

But I want to get images stored in my pc through their path like c:\xyz.jpg. My pc and android device are on same wifi network. Is it possible?

I stored image in wamp server's www folder and can view from my browser as following "`http://192.168.*.***:8080/1.png`" But not able to retrieve same from android app.

My code is working fine for accessing images from any online web site. But I want to access images stored in my pc. Is that possible or not like I access web services running on my localhost from android app over same wifi network.

Comment: Please provide us code you have wrote.

Comment: My code is working fine for accessing images from any online web site. But I want to access images stored in my pc. Is that possible or not like I access web services running on my localhost from android app over same wifi network.

Comment: Check : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: I am already using picasso for asynchronous loading of images. So no need of any other library.

Comment: there may be problem with your URL... ask your web-service developer to make image url accessible.

Comment: I have developed my self and no problem with that. I merely want to ask that is their any way that images from pc can be retrieved from android app...

Comment: is there any error when you  access image??

Comment: No, if images path is of any image on internet. It is shown perfectly

Comment: add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> permission on manifest file and then try....

Comment: already done using this permisssion

Comment: if your URL is correct and accessible through internet it should work... but if there is a problem with your URL its not gonna work until you fix it...

Comment: Switch off the firewall.

Comment: @greenapps . You are right. Switching firewall resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

`and can view from my browser as following "192.168.*.*:8080/1.png" But not able to retrieve same from...`. That is not correct. You should type `http://192.168.*.*:8080/1.png`.

Comment: I am using http://192.168.*.*:8080/1.png already. Sorry didn't write in question but I am trying with it. From android device server time out occur while showing image.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your manifest?

Comment: Yes. I have no problem in accessing images from internet.

Comment: Can you access the image from android browser?

Comment: If you want, you can setup simple java based tomcat server and take images from there :)